# Beginner Resources

Tags: training

I'm looking for resources on how to learn to be a better Project Manager. I started as a 'PM' ( my title doesn't reflect this) at my company about a year a half ago. There isn't a PMO, or a process really, and I have 10+ projects that I'm assigned to when they are already underway with no documentation. I don't have anyone to copy or shadow or get training from, so I'm asking for classes, or videos, or articles, or anything that might help me learn to be a better PM and getting a hold on my projects better.

-Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose you to read following books in order:

1. "Peopleware" by DeMarko and Lister.
2. "Scrum Guide"
3. "Extreme Programming Explained" by Kent Beck.
4. "5 Steps To Kanban"
5. "Goal" by Eliyahu M. Goldratt
6. "Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art" by Steve McConnell
7. "Death March" by by Edward Yourdon
8. "Waltzing with bears" by DeMarko.

There are many others very good ones, but these provided most significant impact on my PM career.

Any soft skills training is also very helpful: communications, general management, people motivation, facilitation.

Comment: I'd suggest The Phoenix Project before The Goal... Rolling Rocks Downhill is good too but not nearly as well known.

Comment: If you're talking about IT/software of course...